# Adding a Logo image on top left of tkinter window along with the title in same line

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, tk-toolkit, tkinter-canvas

I have this logo below and I have to add it in the tkinter window, the logo shall be aligned to top left of window but in same line as the title label.

[image]

```
def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Data Wizard: Automated Data Preprocessing")
        self.root.geometry("800x600")
        self.root.configure(bg='#005792')
             
        # Top layout with title
        self.title_label = tk.Label(self.root, text="Data Wizard: Automated Data Preprocessing", font=("Times New Roman", 22))
        self.title_label.pack(pady=20)
        self.title_label.configure(bg='#005792', fg='#7dd8c5')

        # Middle layout with table frame
        self.table_frame = tk.Frame(self.root, bd=2, relief=tk.GROOVE)
        self.table_frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True, padx=20, pady=10)

        # Create a treeview widget to display table
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self.table_frame, selectmode='browse')
        self.tree.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        # Add scrollbar to the treeview widget
        scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(self.table_frame, orient="vertical", command=self.tree.yview)
        scrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
        self.tree.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

        # Bottom layout with Upload CSV file label and button
        self.bottom_frame = tk.Frame(self.root, bd=2, relief=tk.GROOVE)
        self.bottom_frame.pack(fill=tk.X, padx=20, pady=10)
        self.bottom_frame.configure(bg='#C3C3C3')

        self.upload_label = tk.Label(self.bottom_frame, text="Upload CSV File", font=("Arial", 12))
        self.upload_label.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=10, pady=10)
        self.upload_label.configure(bg='#C3C3C3', fg='#0b1956')

        self.upload_button = tk.Button(self.bottom_frame, text="Browse", command=self.upload_csv)
        self.upload_button.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.new_frame = tk.Frame(self.root, bd=0, relief=tk.GROOVE)
        self.new_frame.pack(fill=tk.X, padx=20, pady=10)
        self.new_frame.configure(bg='#005792')
        
        # Add button to open a new window
        self.new_window_button = tk.Button(self.new_frame, text="Next", command=self.open_new_window)
        self.new_window_button.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, padx=10, pady=10)
```

The window is

[image]

I also tried this following code to do so, and also the PIL methods to do this

```
# Create a PhotoImage object from the image file
        my_img = tk.PhotoImage(file="C:/Users/pdhin/Minor 2/Logo_New.png")

        # Create the title label with the image to the left of the text
        self.title_label = tk.Label(self.root, text="Data Wizard: Automated Data Preprocessing", font=("Times New Roman", 22), image=my_img, compound="left")
        self.title_label.pack(pady=20)
        self.title_label.configure(bg='#005792', fg='#7dd8c5', anchor="e")
```

But everytime an error like this pops up

[image]

Comment: The error is mostly caused by multiple instances of `Tk()`.

Comment: @acw1668 I tried closing those as well but it doesn't works that way also!

Comment: Closing the window does not help. You need to use `Toplevel()` instead of `Tk()` for windows other than the main/root window.

Comment: Also you need to use instance variable `self.my_img` instead of local variable `my_img` to avoid the image from garbage collected.

Comment: I'll try those @acw1668

Answer (score 1):

> the logo shall be aligned to top left of window but in same line as
> the title label.

Add `self.` to `self.my_img = ...`

Code:

```
class App:
    def __init__(self, root):
        ...
        
        self.my_img = tk.PhotoImage(file="p2.png")
             
        # Top layout with title
        self.title_label = tk.Label(self.root, text="Data Wizard: Automated Data Preprocessing",
                                    font=("Times New Roman", 22), image=self.my_img, compound="left")
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: You may have to downsize Logo_New.png. It is too big .